# Flutter - How to build a non-laggy countdown timer with Firestore Timestamp

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I am trying to build a countdown timer that is impervious to users changing the time and date in their phone settings.

The problem I'm having is that the timer I have now gets delayed every now and then (it makes sense why I just don't know how to fix it).

Let's say the current date/time is July 23 @ 07:00 and I'm trying to trying to display to the user how much time is left until later the same day at 19:00.

To do this I used int currentTime = Timestamp.now().seconds; to get the current time from . Firestore in seconds and I have the July 23 19:00 value in unix time (which is `int finalTime = 1563908400;` you can use this site for conversions http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) saved in a Field in my database.

The countdown timer displays

```
int countDown = finalTime - currentTime // in a "HH:MM:SS" format.
```

In order for my main stateful widget to recognize that the currentTime is changing, I have a function that is called every second:

```
// var timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), (timer) {
//
   setState(() {

     getTime(); // This is an async function does the math I described above (countDown = finalTime - currentTime) and is a void function.

   });
```

Now I have the countDown value that refreshes every second and I can display the value in the middle of the screen using a Text widget.

The app looks good for like 10 seconds then it starts skipping a few seconds. I get why this is happening, it's because when the timer fires, it's not necessarily synced with when the Timestamp.now() value changes. I tried lowering the Period duration to 500 milliseconds to see if it made a difference and it kinda did but it's definitely not good enough for my liking.

I am trying to display a countdown timer using Firestore since I want it to be impervious to user change however my timer is displaying values that are delayed.

Comment: Any ideas? I'm thinking the main problem is that I need to be able to rebuild my stateless widget anytime there is a change in my int countdown value (which should be every second)

Comment: Figured it out by myself and am going to create a package for Github for everyone. Please let me know if any of you are interested.

Comment: I'm interested. Please share a link. Thanks.